# How to append ajax event on JSF composite component?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm trying to implement a composite component (`util:compList`) that holds an event (for instance a row select event), and this event triggers an action in the using page of composite.

The composite code (`compList`):

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="list" required="true" type="java.util.Collection" />
    <composite:attribute name="onselect" method-signature="void select(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)" />
    <composite:attribute name="update" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <ui:param name="hasSelectBehavior" value="#{not empty cc.attrs.onselect}" />                
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable ...>
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
                    listener="#{cc.attrs.onselect}"
                    update="#{cc.attrs.update}" />
            <p:column>
               Some content here
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</composite:implementation>
```

Using page code:

```
<util:compList list="#{bean.myList}" 
               selectvalue="#{bean.myEvent}" 
               update=":myFormId, :myFormId:myOtherFormComponent" />
```

This throws the exception:

> Cannot find component with expression "myFormId" referenced from "processTab:j_idt159:myFormId:j_idt161:j_idt162:userNotesTable".

I'm aware that the exception reffers to the fact the composite component cannot find the component ids I'm trying to re-render. Is there any other way to do this correctly?

Comment: Rules are not different in composites. The exception's right. You don't have any element with `id="myFormId"` in generated HTML output. Instead, it's `id="processTab:j_idt159:myFormId"` (whereby you'd need to fix that autogenerated ID part first).